# wordrpess ajax response only showing 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-post

I'm having an issue reading response data from a wordpress ajax function.

I created the script to pull the data and echo a json encoded response:

```
function upd_user_data() {

    global $wpdb; 

    if( isset($_POST['user'] ) ) :

        $userid = $_POST['user'];

        $userdata = array();

        $userdata['key'] = get_usermeta( $userid, 'upd_key' );
        $userdata['hits'] = get_usermeta( $userid, 'upd_hit' );

        $signups = get_users( 'meta_key=upd_referred_user&meta_value='.$key );

        $userdata['signups'] = $signups;

        $userdata['signup_count'] = count($signups);

        echo json_encode($signups);

    else : 

        echo json_encode('Error: no user set.');

    endif;

    die();
}
```

So, I make the call:

```
<?php function upd_get_user_data() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.upd-user').on('click', function(){

        var upduser = $(this).attr('userid');

        var data = {
            action: 'upd_user_data',
            user: upduser
        };

        //Test to make sure it's grabbing the user id attr
        $('#test').html(upduser);

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function( data ) {
            $('#upd-top-row').html( data );
        });

    });
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

The userid is being grabbed from the .attr() just fine as it's value posts to test.  But, the response from the ajax into `#upd-top-row` is only '0', which I assume means an empty result or array.

From reading up on $.post, it's able to detect the response format, so I don't need to define it.  Is this true?  I've alway used $.ajax, but $.post seems simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code below the `upd_user_data()` function.

```
add_action("wp_ajax_upd_user_data", "upd_user_data");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_upd_user_data", "upd_user_data");
```

Comment: I'm not updating any user data, just grabbing it.

Comment: No problem! If you don't mind marking this as the correct answer I would appreciate that!